# Facebook login returns certificate error

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to integrated Facebook login into my app (via Facebook C# SDK). Everything works great on the Emulator, but as soon as I try to log in on the device, I get a certificate error  as soon as I hit 'Login' after entering credentials (see attached image).

Has anyone run into a similar issue?! Any help would be appreciated [image: cert error]

Comment: gotta love how wp7 doesnt have a way of taking screenshots and they force us to do them this way.  do you have some kind of proxy going on with your wifi network? try pulling up https://facebook.com via https in IE9 on your phone.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this somehow? We're facing the same issues with one of our apps, however it seems to be happening only on selected devices...